# Twitter Application That Maintains History?

Tags: twitter, backup, offline

Are there any client applications for Twitter (PC, phone, etc.) that keep a locally backed up record of one's tweets?  Twitter could really be useful as an ongoing activity log, but there's a risk of losing tweets over time because it's not really meant to be an ongoing thing, more of a "here and now" thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the people that you are following in the [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader) and you'll have, besides the backup of all your favorite tweets, also a really powerful search ability. 
Maybe it's not saving them locally, but I think this is even better, than have them locally on your device.

Comment: I've so barely used Twitter yet that it hadn't even occurred to me to watch it through Google Reader.  But I use the latter extensively so that should work out perfectly for me.  And I definitely trust Google's data retention a lot more than Twitter's :)  I may come back someday asking about locally archiving Google Reader as well (don't mind me, I'm a local-archive data retention nut).

Comment: @David I don't mind.. and there are ways of doing it.. but then you'll have to put your locally saved data into the Dropbox.. cause you really don't want to lose your valuable data in 2010... :) The world is moving to the cloud.. I don't want to lose for example my photos because my apartment was blown up.. :D

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you are afraid that Twitter will delete some of your tweets one day? VERY unlikely!

Comment: Yes it is possible, many people have lost tweets before. My timeline does not go all the way back to my first tweet.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed Tweet Nest on my personal webserver, and it has all my tweets backed up: http://pongsocket.com/tweetnest/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TwInbox](http://www.techhit.com/TwInbox/twitter_plugin_outlook.html). It's a pluging for Microsoft Outlook. You can post tweets, RT and post DMs. The tweets on your timeline, your own tweets, DMs and mentions also get saved locally to your hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool for this is [Twistory](http://twistory.net/).

It's a web service through which you can export your Twitter backlog feed to the calendar app of your choice (e.g. Google Calendar, iCal, Outlook). You can only access your tweet history back to the point when you enabled Twistory to record it though.